# Computing the confidence interval for cohen's d?

Tags: statistics

When I have the standard error of d (standard mean difference), how I should compute the confidence interval of it?
 If you know a tutorial please introduce to me.

Comment: [This paper](https://www.uvm.edu/~dhowell/methods/Supplements/Confidence%20Intervals%20on%20Effect%20Size.pdf) discusses effect sizes and their CIs. The part on two samples is directly applicable to your Question.

Answer (score 0):

**Background.** Suppose you have two independent random samples, say $X_1, \dots, X_n$ from $\mathsf{Norm}(\mu_x, \sigma_x)$ and $Y_1, \dots, Y_m$ from $\mathsf{Norm}(\mu_y, \sigma_y).$ If you test
$H_0: \mu_x = \mu_y$ against $H_a: \mu_x \ne \mu_y,$ you should use
a Welch separate variances t test. If you are fairly certain that
$\sigma_x = \sigma_y,$ you might use the pooled two-sample t test.
Recently, use of the pooled test has been deprecated, except when
sample sizes are very small or there is substantial prior evidence
or experience that $\sigma_x = \sigma_y.$

**Effect size.** Cohen's d (earlier Hedge's g) is intended to measure 'effect size'
in the pooled setting. Effect size is defined as $\theta = \frac{\mu_x - \mu_y}{\sigma},$ where $\sigma = \sigma_x = \sigma_y.$

Commonly, $\mu_x$ is estimated by $\bar X,\,$ $\mu_y$ is estimated by $\bar Y,\,$
and $\sigma$ is estimated by 
$$S_p = = \sqrt{\frac{(m-1)S_x^2 + (n-1)S_y^2}{m+n-2}},$$ where $S_x$ and $S_y$ are sample standard deviations of the two samples (taken individually).
Then $\theta$ is estimated by Cohen's d:
$$d = \frac{\bar X - \bar Y}{S_p}.$$

This is the same as Student's pooled t statistic, but the context in which it is used is somewhat different: 
If $H_0$ is true, then $T = (\bar X - \bar Y)/S_p$ has Student's t distribution
with degrees of freedom $\nu = m + n - 2.$ However, effect size is mainly of
interest when $H_0$ is false. If $H_0$ is rejected, a traditional
approach has been to make a confidence interval (CI) for $\delta = \mu_x - \mu_y$
and the formula for that CI can be found in most elementary statistics texts.

**CI for effect size.** You want to find a CI for $\theta.$ Unfortunately,
when $H_0$ is not true, the distribution of $d$ has a non-central t distribution.
The article I linked in my comment explains how to use R statistical software
to get a CI for $\theta$ based on $d,$ using commands in one of the R libraries.
A program for a parametric bootstrap CI for $\theta$ is illustrated below.

**Example.** Consider fake data, with a random sample of $n = 10$ values 
$X_i \sim \mathsf{Norm}(115, 10)$ and an independent random sample
of $m = 20$ values $Y_i \sim \mathsf{Norm}(100, 10).$ Thus $H_0$ is false,
$\delta = 15$ and $\theta = 15/10 = 1.5.$  Below we show how the data are
generated, and do a pooled t test of $H_0$ vs. $H_0.$ It happens that $H_0$
is rejected and that a 95% CI for $\delta$ is $(2.18, 17.38).$
The CI contains $\bar X - \bar Y$ (as it must); it also happens to
contain $\delta = 15.$ Also, $S_p = 9.58,$ which not far from $\sigma = 10,$
considering the small sample sizes.

```
set.seed(318);  n = 10;  m = 20
mu.x = 115;  mu.y = 100;  sg = 10
x = rnorm(n, mu.x, sg);  y = rnorm(m, mu.y, sg)
t.test(x, y, var.eq=T)

        Two Sample t-test

data:  x and y 
t = 2.6352, df = 28, p-value = 0.01355
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0 
95 percent confidence interval:
  2.177199 17.377599 
sample estimates:
mean of x mean of y 
 110.4174  100.6400 
s.p = sqrt((9*var(x) + 19*var(y))/ 28);  s.p
## 9.579947
```

The data are plotted below:

[image]

In order to get a CI for $\theta,$ we can use a bootstrap procedure.
If we knew the true distribution of Cohen's d in this situation, we could
use it to get bounds $L$ and $U$ such that $P(L < d < U) = 1.96,$ so that
a 95% CI for $\theta$ would be $(L, U).$

Not knowing this distribution, we
use available data $\bar X, \bar Y,$ and $S_p$ as estimates of $\mu_x, \mu_y,$
and $\sigma,$ respectively. Then we 're-sample' $B = 10,000$ values of $d = T,$
and we take quantiles 0.025 and 0.975 of the resulting re-sampled distribution of $d,$ to serve as approximate confidence bounds. The resulting 95% CI for
$\theta$ is $(0.634, 5.013),$ which contains the observed value of $d = T = 2.64$
(from the t test above).

Because we simulated the data, we know that the true
effect size is $\theta = 1.5$ and the CI happens to contain that value also.
[The bootstrap procedure involves simulation as a computational device. For
the same data, it will give slightly different results on each run. Use the seed
`123` as shown to get exactly the same result; omit the `set.seed` statement
or change the seed for a fresh run. One additional run gave the CI $(0.633, 5.012).]$

```
set.seed(123); B = 10^4  
n=10; m=20; a.obs=mean(x); b.obs=mean(y); sg.obs=sqrt( (9*var(x)+19*var(y)) /28 )
a.obs;  b.obs;  sg.obs  #values observed in sample (from above)
## 110.4174
## 100.64
## 9.579947
d.re = replicate(B, t.test(rnorm(n,a.obs,sg.obs),rnorm(m,b.obs,sg.obs), var.eq=T)$stat)
L.re = quantile(d.re, .025); U.re = quantile(d.re, .975)
as.numeric(c(L.re,U.re))
## 0.6337554 5.0126049
```

The figure below shows a histogram of the bootstrapped values of Cohen's d
along with the bootstrap confidence bounds (red).

[image]

*Note:* As a trick to simplify the
R code for the Bootstrap procedure, we use the built-in function `t.test` and
use only the test statistic $T$ (obtained with `$stat`) for the re-sampled value `d.re`
of Cohen's d.

Comment: Dear Bruce, 
Thank you so much for your informative answer.